# Approach for tagging in contentEditable div

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am trying to build a user input (contentEditable div) for a chat where someone can write something and tag someone like `hello @user32`. In that case, I want the `@user32` to be replaced by a link and formatted.

I am trying to understand what would be the best approach for the client and the server.

1. Should the client (javascript) remove the `<a src="xxx">User32</a>` tags before sending the message to the server `@user32` in the message? And each client receiving the message would process it to display it?
2. Should the client send the complete message including the link to the server and the servers cleans it before inserting in the DB?
3. Should I insert in the DB the complete message including the link without pre/post-processing on the server or client ?

I would think option 1 would be the best to keep clean data so it is not client-dependent, but I am concerned about having a visible formatted message in the contentEditable div and maintaining hidden data to be sent to the server or is there an easy way to do this? Or should I still go with option 1 and clean the message before sending? i.e. replacing all links with a specific tag/class the raw `@user32`?

Answer (score 0):

I did have used [this library](https://podio.github.io/jquery-mentions-input/) in the past and worked out pretty well for me, even that in the time didnt used a content editable div, but a larger input.

I suggest that you tried it out and check if it fit your needs.

Comment: So using this library you would send everything to the server, including html markup ?

Comment: Nope, you'll send only the text. The lib will handle the display. Note that it doesnt use content editable div, so i'm not sure if it will fit. Maybe you could change your approach for a more "standard" one...